# display thumbnails of video in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

This is my code which is working perfectly . Here i m accessing array of videos in my tableview.....

This is my array of videos and videos are in my bundle...

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
             videos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                         @"video 1",
                         @"video 2",

                         nil];
        }
```

Accessing videos in tableview .....

```
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        NSIndexPath *index ;

        index = [self.table indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"%@----hello",indexPath);

// taking path of video from bundle 
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"mp4"];

//declare nsurl and mpmoviplayer globally..
        movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];


  // <converting image in thumbnail...
        AVAsset* videoAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:movieURL];

        AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset];

        Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([videoAsset duration]);
        CMTime midpoint = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600);
        NSError* error = nil;
        CMTime actualTime;

        //generating image...
        CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:midpoint actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];


   // show image in uiimage of tableviewcell....
        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:halfWayImage];
        cell.textLabel.text= [videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        return cell;

        }
```

Accessing videos in other view through Segue......

```
        - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
                if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailsSeg"]) {

//playing video in other view controller....

                    [[player view] setFrame: self.view.frame];
                    [self.view addSubview: [player view]];

                    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];

//using sequel for destination controller
                    [segue destinationViewController] ;
               }
        }
```

Done....

Comment: your video is on server or in document directory?

Comment: If it's working perfectly, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: it is in documentary list . Now i want to show thumbnails of videos in tableview its only showing names of video in it .

Comment: @DarshanMothreja videos are stored with same name which you show in table?

Comment: see my code i have edited . Now i want display thumbnail of videos in tableview its only showing video names in it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "video" it is instance of ALAsset, then you can use - (CGImageRef)thumbnail method:

```
UIImage* thumb = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[video thumbnail]];
```

If you use AVAsset to present video objects, you can use [AVAssetImageGenerator](http://goo.gl/uLmgWB) to get image at specific time and use this image to generate [thumb](http://goo.gl/Eaamk1).

You can do something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSURL* urlToVideo = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localPathToVideo"];
    AVAsset* videoAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:urlToVideo];

    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset];

    Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([videoAsset duration]);
    CMTime midpoint = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600);
    NSError* error = nil;
    CMTime actualTime;

    CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:midpoint actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

    UIImage* resultUIImage = nil;
    if (halfWayImage != NULL) {
        resultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:halfWayImage];

        CGImageRelease(halfWayImage);

        //resize image (use some code for resize)
        //<>
        //TODO: call some method to resize image
        UIImage* resizedImage = resultUIImage;
        //<>

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //TODO: set resized image to destination
            //if(cell.asset == videoAsset)
            //{
            //   cell.thumb.image = resizedImage
            //}
        });         
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //TODO: do something if you can't generate preview.
        });
    }
});
```

**UPD**

---

Explanation, why developer should use ALAsset or AVAsset to present video in application. Video it is binary file with complex structure, to access to video data you can wright your own library, and generate thumbs from video with your methods. But iOS SDK provide some methods to working with video. The SDK contain ALFoundation framework, it framework let to work with video at any path (in your opinion in Documents directory), you have to know only video URL (or local path). If you get video from AssetsLibrary (photos), then you have ALAsset (presents some item from Library), ALAsset has type property and thumb property, and URL to asset.

---

To use ALFoundation you should import this library:

```
@import AVFoundation;
```

To use AssetsLibrary you should import this library:

```
@import AssetsLibrary;
```

---

Also I think you should read presented links, before write code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to support video in Document directory.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion can you explain it simply coz I'm new in developing

Comment: i m not able to declare .. 
 AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset];

Comment: You've forgot about @import AVFoundation. I've updated my answer.

Comment: now where to use "resizedImage" 
i have implemented your code in my method "prepareForseque"

Comment: I think you can implement this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:. I thought you wanted to use thumbs to display in cell. Was I wrong?

Comment: ya now i only want to display thumbs in cell

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand question.

Comment: see in this page here he is showing video thumbs in tableview ...
my code is working perfect and showing video name and after tapping on it also playing the video now i want to show video thumb on tableview
http://gladiatorapps.com/?p=91

Comment: You can insert my code to method that generate cells, and uncomment commented code (it marked "resized image to destination"), but you should change cell.thumb to your cell's property name with image view.

Comment: thanx @Andrew it worked for there was a silly mistake done by ..
i have edited my code which is the Actually code ..
have look

Comment: I glad to you find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Display thumbnail of Video you can do following, I have added both Swift and Objective-C code to generate a thumbnail of a video.

Swift 3.X and 4.0

```
do {
                let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL as! URL)
                let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
                imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
                let cgImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(3, 1), actualTime: nil)
                let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
                imgView.image = thumbnail
            }catch{
                print("Error is : \(error)")
            }
```

Where `videoURL` is a path of your video file.

Objective-C code:

```
-(UIImage *)generateThumbImage : (NSString *)filepath
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    CMTime time = [asset duration];
    time.value = 1000; //Time in milliseconds
    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);  // CGImageRef won't be released by ARC

    return thumbnail;
}
```